# Inheritance w/ Angular's 'Controller As' vs. $scope

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

### tl:dr;

I want to consider the 'controller as' approach to simplify my inheritance process however I see some pitfalls around dependency injection and use in directives.

---

#### preface

I've been working on a pretty big Angular application for the last 6 months.  I come from a more OOP language background but feel I've adapted fairly well to some of the quirkiness of javaScript and Angular.

With an application of this complexity, I think it necessitates **great** architectural solutions.  I've elected to have baseController classes that UI controllers can inherit from using the current approach below.

## current approach

All the current UI views/components/etc. are utilizing the *$scope* as the view model approach, aka. the *classic approach*.  I achieved the controller inheritance like so:

NxBaseUiController

```
var NxBaseUiController = function($scope)
{
    $scope.isLoggedIn = function(){}
    $scope.doSomethingElse = function(){}
}
```

Here's a subclass base controller and it's inheritance

NxBaseListUiController

```
var NxBaseListUiController = function($scope)
{
    var NxBaseUiController = require( './NxBaseUiController' )
    NxBaseUiController.apply( this, arguments )
    NxBaseListUiController .prototype = Object.create( NxBaseUiController.prototype );

    $scope.query = require( './QueryModel' ).new()
}
```

What's crazy about this approach is that I'm having to maintain 2 series of inheritance all while keeping in mind of the existing NG scope inheritance that takes place in the view hierarchy.  You can see this in the following UML diagram:

[image: Crnt inheritance UML diagram]
src - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTiCL.png

This all works so far, but moving onto a new section of the app, I want to start looking at the 'Controller As' syntax to see if there can be any simplification of the above approach.

## questions

In all the examples I've seen of the 'controller as' approach, any methods attached are *not* defined on the prototype but rather the actual constructor like so:

```
function SomeController($scope)
{
   this.foo = function(){}; 
}
```

**Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to define the controller methods on the prototype?**

The only reason I see attaching to the prototype as being problematic is you lose reference to your injected dependencies.

---

I realize I am coming at this from a very OO approach, however w/ an application of this size, being able to draw upon development patterns like inheritance seems necessary to solve code duplication.

**Am I approaching this completely backwards?  Are there any proven methods to achieving some semblance of inheritance in the controllers that doesn't require some wonky hack to work w/ the $scope?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you can't use the prototype so long as you are OK with losing the ability to have actual private data vs having conventionally private data.

Let me explain with code:

```
function MyClass($http){
  var privateData = 123,
      $this = this;

  $this.getAnswer = function(){
     return privateData;
  };
}

MyClass.$inject = ['$http'];
```

In that example you can't actually change `privateData` once the class has been instantiated.

```
function MyClass($http){
  this._privateData = 123;
  this.$http = $http;
}

MyClass.$inject = ['$http']; 

MyClass.prototype = {
   getAnswer: function(){
      return this._privateData;
   },
   callHome: function(){
      var _this = this;

      _this.$http.get('/api/stuff')
         .success(function(data){
            _this.stuff = data;
         });
   }
};
```

In that example I am simply using a convention of prefixing my properties with an underscore (`_`) to signal that they should be treated as private.

Unless you are building a re-usable library however, this might not be a big deal.

Mind you some of this get's much simpler with ES6, so I would look into something like [6to5](https://6to5.org/) or [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) if I were you. It might gel a little better with your OO background to write code like this:

```
//100% valid ES6
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
   constructor(something){
      super(something, 'foo');
   }

   someMethod(){
      return this.foo;
   }
}
```

Comment: how are you handling the Angular injected dependencies when you use the prototype based approach?

Comment: @jusopi - I've updated the example to show how to use injected dependencies.

Comment: If you are using inheritence, it get's a bit wonky for minification safe `$inject` but basically looks like this: `$inject = BaseClass.$inject.concat('$compile');`

Comment: ooh good catch. Currently we're not using any minification aside from whitespace removal.

Comment: Thanks for the lead on 6to5.org.  After doing some research, we're going to start writing ES6 style javascript to tackle some of the more complex inheritance issues along w. using the Controller-As syntax.

Comment: @jusopi - To balance out that viewpoint, you should read up on some of the counter-arguments to classical inheritance in JavaScript. There are many compelling reasons why it's a bad idea, and that JavaScript lends itself much more towards a composition model. This article is a good start: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I did read this back in January.  And I do prefer composition over inheritance.  Let me rephrase this whole scenario differently. 

I have several views that require a call to fetch our appData via a service method `getAppData` when the UI loads. Depending on certain factors we either say return immediately via `$q.when( appData )` or we make a call out.  Point being every view does then and then calls `getViewData` afterwards. Copying this code per controller is bad. This is just a basic case of why I don't see a better alternative than using some inheritance paradigm.

Comment: @jusopi - Sorry, didn't mean for that to come off wrong. More just a heads up, that although the new `class` syntax in ES6 makes it much easier to do prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, there may be some nicer ways accomplish the same thing. I come from a C# background, so in many ways I'm still getting used to *thinking* in JavaScript. Lots of thought provoking material out there.

Comment: totally agree.  DIdn't take it wrong at all.  I come from a Java/Flex background and while there are some niceties in JavaScript, there are many pain points.  Something we take for granted in C# or AS3, we must jump through hoops to accomplish in JS.  When I get there, I sometimes question if there is a better way, a flip-side if you will.  Thanks for engaging me w. your answers and input btw.